# Как записать переменную типа string в printf и scanf

Tags: c

Здравствуйте интересует такой вопрос.
Допустим есть некая переменная

```
string name;
```

Как я могу реализовать ее ввод\вывод через scanf и printf ?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Смешав французский с нижегородским...

```
printf("%s",name.c_str());

char buf[много];
scanf("%s",buf);
name = buf;
```

Вы, надеюсь, в курсе - раз хотите именно `scanf` - что `scanf("%s",...` читает **одно слово**?